# How to add a custom web page in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to make a web-page which displays the dynamic web page - basically it displays a table comprising of Name, IP_Address, and Group Name with used check/uncheck box. This webpage can run on a different tcp socket so it can be 
https://myjenkins:5909 . Next, I want to add this table information in the mongo-db and read back the data and show on the web page - that table. What are the required steps for me? First is it possible?  Here is my understanding that I have to write a back hand code using Jenkins plugin. Now, how to add the front end page like my custom page in Jenkins. Also, how database can be handled by the backhand Jenkins plugin? Sorry, I am new to these things. Any idea or details will help me. Also, is it possible to use LDAP based user id and password in my form.